# using destructuring switch statement in es6

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ecmascript-6, switch-statement, destructuring

Is there a way to use the destructuring feature in switch ... case statement instead of using nested if else statements ??

For example I would expect something like this :

```
const tall = true;
const clean = true;

switch ([tall, clean]) {
    case [true,true]: 
        console.log("Perfect"); 
        break;
    case [false,true]: 
        console.log("Ok"); 
        break;
    case [true,false]: 
        console.log("Not so good"); 
        break;
    default: 
        console.log("Terrible");
}
```

instead of using :

```
if (tall){
    if (clean){
        ...
    }else{
        ...
    }
}else{
    if (clean){
        ...
    }else{
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

No, this has nothing to do with destructuring and No, you cannot use array literals in a `switch` statement since distinct objects never compare equal.

What you *can* do in your case is to map your two booleans to an integer score:

```
switch (clean * 2 + tall) {
    case 3: 
        console.log("Perfect");
        break;
    case 2: 
        console.log("Ok");
        break;
    case 1: 
        console.log("Not so good");
        break;
    case 0: 
        console.log("Terrible");
}
```

or the equivalent array lookup:

```
console.log(["Terrible", "Not so good", "Ok", "Perfect"][clean * 2 + tall]);
```

You might even want to make the bitwise magic more obvious:

```
switch (tall << 1 | clean << 0) {
    case true << 1 | true << 0:
        console.log("Perfect"); 
        break;
    case false << 1 | true << 0:
        console.log("Ok"); 
        break;
    case true << 1 | false << 0:
        console.log("Not so good"); 
        break;
    case false << 1 | false << 0:
        console.log("Terrible");
        break;
}
```

You can also call a helper `function score(a, b) { return a << 1 | b << 0 }` in both the `switch` and the `case`s.

Comment: @Li357 Oops, typo.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you can only use literals in a switch statement and you can't use primitive objects as keys in an array, so you can't do a mapping like:

```
{[true,true]: 'Perfect'
...}
```

Too bad. I wonder if there are languages where you can have a list/array as dictionary key.

I still might be tempted to do something like this which I think is quite readable (though it might get rejected in a code review!):

```
function hashKey([tall, clean]) {
  return `${tall}_${clean}`
}

let valMap = {
  'true_true': 'Perfect',
  'false_true': 'Ok',
  'true_false': 'Not so good',
  'false_false': 'Terrible'
}

console.log(valMap[hashKey([true, true ])])
```

Comment: maybe elixirs pattern matching (https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/pattern-matching.html) is what your looking for? In elixir you replace most if / else statements with switch ( in elixir `case`) and pattern matching. Since pattern matching in elixir is so powerful, the code gets more readable and there are no `if x do-stuff else if y do-stuff else do-stuff`. I would love js's destructing in switch statements.

Comment: Elm and haskell pattern matching can also handle situations like these. I think it's common amongst functional languages.

Comment: > I wonder if there are languages where you can have a list/array as dictionary key.

I do this sort of thing in python fairly often. Python allows you to have dicts keyed by tuples.

Comment: Ruby lets you have anything as a map key.

Answer (score -3):

Can do something like the following:

```js
const tall = true;
const clean = false;

switch (true) {
    case tall && clean: 
        console.log("Perfect"); 
        break;
    case !tall && clean: 
        console.log("Ok"); 
        break;
    case tall && !clean: 
        console.log("Not so good"); 
        break;
    default: 
        console.log("Terrible");
}
```

Comment: Don't do that. It's not better than a series of `if`/`else if`s.